# Reduce/mute node.js stack trace

Tags: node.js, localhost, http-status-code-404, stack-trace

If I try running localhost:3000/foo/bar, I'm supposed to get a 404 error. I do get that error and a huge stack trace. Currently I don't need such a long stack trace, is there a way to mute it?

```
if (!foo) {
    var err = new Error('404');
    err.status = 404;
    return next(err);
  }
  res.render('bar/foo', {
    foo: foo.toJSON()
  });
```

Comment: Are you using express?

Comment: @staaar, yes, i'm using express.

Comment: What middleware are you using?

Comment: @mscdex, I'm not sure as to what is implied by middleware, could you please explain?

Comment: The modules that you're `app.use()`ing.